# Exception while trying to open sqlite DB with having pagesize as 64KB

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

I have a java program which interacts with SQLite DB having journal_mode as delete.

This program works fine for all DB and I am able to do transactions as far as DB has pagesize of 32 KB.

But there is one sqlite DB which is having pagesize as 64 KB. And when I try to execute
stmt.executeQuery();
on that DB, it gives me exception
java.sql.SQLException: [SQLITE_NOTADB]  File opened that is not a database file (file is encrypted or is not a database)

Can anybody please let me know what could be the solution for this? This DB is not encrypted and having journal_mode as delete only.

I am able to open this DB with SQLITESpy tool though.

Thanks

Comment: Can you open that file with any other SQLite tool?

Comment: Yes I am able to open this DB  with sqlitespy tool.

Comment: What is the result of `SELECT sqlite_version();` and `PRAGMA compile_options;` in both SQLiteSpy and your JDBC driver?

Comment: From program, version = 3.6.20 but when I try to run PRAGMA compile_options; it gives me exception saying no resultset.             From SQLiteSpy, version = 3.7.8 and compile_options are list of options ENABLE_COLUMN_METADATA,ENABLE_FTS1 etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using 64 KB pages requires [SQLite 3.7.1](http://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_7_1.html) or later.

Answer (score 1):

If the database is open by another application and has wal and shm files open I get the same strange error. Since i do not want to bother with such strange design internall details I am using the following workaround:

```
echo ".dump" | sqlite3 database.db |  sqlite3 dbcopy.db
```

and work on the copy for queries. I even get protected from database corruption problems this way that seem to plague the "new" sqlite design as well. I wish the sqlite designers would make sure that there external interface is much more stable and clean and does not show such internal design problems as failures and corruptions.